# Given regular decagon $ABCDEFGHIJ$, and midpoint $M$ of $AB$, prove that $AD$, $CJ$, $EM$ concur

Tags: geometry, polygons

> Let there be a regular decagon $ABCDEFGHIJ$, and $M$ the midpoint of $AB$. Prove $AD$, $CJ$, and $EM$ are concurrent.

I was going to do this problem by making AD and CJ pass through a point K, and construct EK and EM, and prove EKM is a straight line, as shown in the diagram below. But I got stuck because I cannot prove that JC is parallel to AB, and AD is parallel to BC - this is the only step I need to prove in order to solve the question. Is there a quick way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

PS I also need to prove triangles KDC and AJK are congruent, but I think that this will be easier if I prove the parallel lines first.

[image]

Comment: I have replaced your graphics by a more "readable" one...

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie

Comment: Don't overthink the parallel lines question - you can simply use the symmetry through the perpendicular bisector of $AB$

Comment: @ChrisLewis thank you for your help - i got the question now

Comment: wait i missed the last step i cant prove its a straight line @ChrisLewis help?

Comment: You can compute $\angle AKM$ and $\angle EKD$ and show they are equal.

Comment: I think Ceva will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the sides of the decagon be of unit length. Then:
$$
EC=2\sin72°=4\sin36°\cos36°=4sc,
$$
where I set for simplicity:
$$
c=\cos36°={1+\sqrt5\over4},\quad s=\sin36°=\sqrt{1-c^2}.
$$
If $K$ is the intersection of $AD$ and $JC$, we also have:
$$
AK=CK=1,\quad DK=JK=JC-1=2c.
$$
Let then $H$ be the projection of $K$ onto $AB$. We have:
$$
MH=2c-(c+AM)=c-{1\over2},
\quad
HK=s.
$$
Note that $\angle ECJ=90°$ by [Thales's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem).
We can then compute:
$$
\tan(\angle JKM)=\tan(\angle HMK)={HK\over MH}={s\over c-1/2},
\quad
\tan(\angle CKE)={EC\over CK}=4sc
$$
and it is easy to check that these expressions are equal, because:
$$
{1\over c-1/2}={4\over\sqrt5-1}=\sqrt5+1=4c.
$$
Hence $\angle JKM=\angle CKE$ and as a cosequence
$\angle AKM=\angle EKD$ and $MKE$ are aligned, as it was to be proved.

Comment: wait your proof for angle JKM does not make sense - tan(angle JKM) = JM/MK

Comment: oh wait its because of projections - thats on me (sorry)

Answer (score 2):

Let $AD$ intersect $JC$ at $X$. Let $O$ be the center of the dodecagon. Due to symmetry, $B, X, O$ are collinear. Easy to see that $ABX$ and $JXO$ are similar isosceles triangles. We have $EJ=2JO=2JX$ and $AM=\frac 12 AB=\frac 12 AX$, so
$$\frac{EJ}{JX}=2=\frac{XA}{AM}.$$
Since $\angle MAX=\angle XJE$, it follows by SAS that $\triangle MAX\sim\triangle XJE$. Now it's easy to see that $E,X,M$ are collinear.